# uniq_by to collect unique profile views by IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a profile views model that records the user_id, guest_ip and timestamps.

```
>> @user.profileviews
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Profileview id: 3, guest_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_id: 8, created_at: "2014-03-09 17:38:00", updated_at: "2014-03-09 17:38:00">, #<Profileview id: 4, guest_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_id: 8, created_at: "2014-03-09 17:40:04", updated_at: "2014-03-09 17:40:04">, #<Profileview id: 5, guest_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_id: 8, created_at: "2014-03-09 17:40:10", updated_at: "2014-03-09 17:40:10">, #<Profileview id: 9, guest_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_id: 8, created_at: "2014-03-09 17:41:44", updated_at: "2014-03-09 17:41:44">, #<Profileview id: 10, guest_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_id: 8, created_at: "2014-03-09 17:45:39", updated_at: "2014-03-09 17:45:39">, #<Profileview id: 11, guest_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_id: 8, created_at: "2014-03-09 17:46:29", updated_at: "2014-03-09 17:46:29">, #<Profileview id: 12, guest_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_id: 8, created_at: "2014-03-09 17:47:00", updated_at: "2014-03-09 17:47:00">, #<Profileview id: 15, guest_ip: "127.0.0.1", user_id: 8, created_at: "2014-03-09 17:53:01", updated_at: "2014-03-09 17:53:01">]>
```

This (@user.profileviews) returns the ActiveRecord array of profile views recorded on a user's profile. Now I want to see the view count which can be accomplished by `@user.provileviews.count`. Then I want to extract the uniq views.

I tried to do that by using @user.profileviews.uniq.count. Of course does not work as the uniquness must be according to IP only. I found [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-uniq_by) at the Ruby on Rails API. I did something like that which obviously doesn't work: `@userviews = @user.profileviews.uniq_by { |i| i.uniq? }`

Any clue how to make it work? Or any other way/idea to get the unique (by IP) views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below using [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

> If a *block* is given, it will use the return value of the block for comparison.It compares values using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency.

```
 @user.profileviews.uniq { |i| i.guest_ip }
 @user.profileviews.uniq(&:guest_ip)
```

Comment: Good answer @Arup. I heard that the syntax form (&:x) it is slower than { |i| i.x }. Is that true?

Comment: @Rafa Yes,,, There also a post in stackoverflow I think.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to take a look at `ActiveRecord::Calculations#count`. When you do something like:

```
@user.profileviews.group(:guest_ip).count
# => { '2.3.4.5' => 5, '1.2.3.4' => 3, ...}
```

You get a hash with pageviews grouped by ip. So you get the number of unique pageviews (number of hash keys) and the number of all pageviews (sum of the values) with just one query to the database.